# c# - Text File to Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, text-files

i want to turn a text file, into a dictionary of Lists. The dictionary is declared in its separate class, BaseDict, as :

```
public static Dictionary<string, List<string>> myLists = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

The method that populates it is in a different class, and is the following :

```
 public void TextFileToDictionary2()
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(File_Path))
        {
            string line = null;
            List<string> InputLineList = new List<string>();
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                InputLineList.Clear();

                // Slice Substrings
                string AP = line.Substring(0, 7);
                string Address = line.Substring(8, 45);
                string JDate = line.Substring(54, 3);
                string BMFline = line.Substring(57, 6);
                string POD = line.Substring(68, 11);
                string DateApok = line.Substring(79, 4);
                string checkdigit1 = line.Substring(83, 1);
                string poso = line.Substring(84, 9);
                string checkdigit2 = line.Substring(93, 1);
                string GDate = line.Substring(94, 8);
                string AType = line.Substring(102, 2);
                string NinPacket = line.Substring(106, 5);

                // Construct List
                InputLineList.Add(AP);
                InputLineList.Add(Address);
                InputLineList.Add(JDate);
                InputLineList.Add(BMFline);
                InputLineList.Add(POD);
                InputLineList.Add(DateApok);
                InputLineList.Add(checkdigit1);
                InputLineList.Add(poso);
                InputLineList.Add(checkdigit2);
                InputLineList.Add(GDate);
                InputLineList.Add(AType);
                InputLineList.Add(NinPacket);

                //Console.WriteLine(InputLineList[0] + InputLineList[1] + InputLineList[2]);
                //BaseDict.niarxosfileadv.Add(POD, InputLineList);
                BaseDict.myLists.Add(POD, InputLineList);
                Console.WriteLine(BaseDict.myLists[POD][0] + BaseDict.myLists[POD][1] + BaseDict.myLists[POD][2]);


            }
            Console.WriteLine("#");
            Console.WriteLine(BaseDict.myLists["70503490702"][0] + BaseDict.myLists["70503490702"][1] + BaseDict.myLists["70503490702"][2]);
            Console.WriteLine(BaseDict.myLists["33221051805"][0] + BaseDict.myLists["33221051805"][1] + BaseDict.myLists["33221051805"][2]);

            foreach  (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> kvp in BaseDict.myLists)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("#");
                Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + "@" +  kvp.Value[0] + kvp.Value[1]);
                Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + "@" + BaseDict.myLists[kvp.Key][0]  +  BaseDict.myLists[kvp.Key][1]);
            }
        }
    }
```

and the input file looks like this:

```
0000039#XXXXXX                25000YYYYYYY    #1491505400010070503490702030750000078006201
0000040#zzzzzz                21300FFFFFFF    #1491487800010533221051805030720000245001201
```

My problem is that it doesnt seem like the Dictionary is being loaded correctly, this statement:

```
BaseDict.myLists.Add(POD, InputLineList);
Console.WriteLine(BaseDict.myLists[POD][0] + BaseDict.myLists[POD][1] + BaseDict.myLists[POD][2]);
```

produces the correct result for the key value pairs, but the following ones (with the hardcoded keys, the ones after the loop) give me only the value of the last key entered in the dictionary.

Comment: Are you sure all your POD's are unique?

Comment: string POD = line.Substring(68, 11); in this example, because i ve edited the lines to remove some sensitive information, its the two hardcoded values you see below:

Comment: 70503490702, 33221051805, those are being produced by string POD = line.Substring....

Comment: I am sure, because the foreach loop produces the correct keys, but incorrect values for each of the correct keys( the same one for everything )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You rewrite your list in each loop. List is a reference type, so you should create new List on each loop to prevent rewriting data in Dictionary

It's also better to use some class rather than list of substrings

```
List<string> InputLineList;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
          InputLineList = new List<string>();
           // InputLineList.Clear();

            // Slice Substrings
            string AP = line.Substring(0, 7);
            string Address = line.Substring(8, 45);
            string JDate = line.Substring(54, 3);
            string BMFline = line.Substring(57, 6);
            string POD = line.Substring(68, 11);
            string DateApok = line.Substring(79, 4);
            string checkdigit1 = line.Substring(83, 1);
            string poso = line.Substring(84, 9);
            string checkdigit2 = line.Substring(93, 1);
            string GDate = line.Substring(94, 8);
            string AType = line.Substring(102, 2);
            string NinPacket = line.Substring(106, 5);

            // Construct List
            InputLineList.Add(AP);
            InputLineList.Add(Address);
            InputLineList.Add(JDate);
            InputLineList.Add(BMFline);
            InputLineList.Add(POD);
            InputLineList.Add(DateApok);
            InputLineList.Add(checkdigit1);
            InputLineList.Add(poso);
            InputLineList.Add(checkdigit2);
            InputLineList.Add(GDate);
            InputLineList.Add(AType);
            InputLineList.Add(NinPacket);

            //Console.WriteLine(InputLineList[0] + InputLineList[1] + InputLineList[2]);
            //BaseDict.niarxosfileadv.Add(POD, InputLineList);
            BaseDict.myLists.Add(POD, InputLineList);
            Console.WriteLine(BaseDict.myLists[POD][0] + BaseDict.myLists[POD][1] + BaseDict.myLists[POD][2]);


        }
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a prompt response.